# Axis2 soap websevice - nullpointerexception

Tags: java, web-services, nullpointerexception

I have one **axis2** web service calling the other web service in java program. It works fine for first time, but if invoke the process for 2nd time, the axis2 web service will throw an exception as following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:135)
        org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:130)
        org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:825)
        org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:271)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Any idea?